# Using module: url_alter and it's hook: hook_url_outbound_alter()

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

**hook_url_outbound_alter()**

I am struggling to find any documentation or explanation for how to use this hook. I have a page: `node/1221` and when it look like so: `node/1221/profile/chn/3` It loads a profile for that user.

I want pretty URL's so that when the user visits `departments/pch/chn/profile/3` I want it to actually load `node/1221/profile/chn/3`

I am pretty sure the hook should help me with this but not sure how it works.

*Note: Using drupal 6, tried aliases but they didn't work.*

**2nd update:**
The `3` in the URL is a profile ID that I want to pass on to another URL. I have `node/1221/profile/chn/3` working because it has a panel that grabs the `%4` argument and passes it to a view inside the panel. Hope this gives more context.

Currently trying:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_boot()
 */
function pathargs_boot() {
  // remain empty, only needed to let Drupal bootstrap system know to load this module earlier.
}

/**
 * Will define custom_url_rewrite_inbound(). If url_alter is enabled 
 * Pathargs inbound alter will be called by its implementation of 
 * custom_url_rewrite_inbound() instead.
 */
if (!function_exists('custom_url_rewrite_inbound')) {
  function custom_url_rewrite_inbound(&$result, $path, $path_language) {
    return pathargs_url_inbound_alter($result, $path, $path_language);
  }
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_url_inbound_alter()
 */
function pathargs_url_inbound_alter(&$result, $path, $path_language) {
  watchdog('Path Arguments', "$path + $original_path");
  if($result == 'chn') {
    $result = 'node/1222/chn/profile/3';
  }
}
```

Still not working... visiting www.domain.com/chn does nothing.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly node/1221/profile/chn/3 means in your site.
Is your node gets the URL and loads data accordingly ?
Maybe it is irrelevant to your question, but in order to maybe direct you to a simpler solution, I rather understand the wider picture...
In any case, I have experience with URL Alter, and I will be happy to help if possible

Comment: Thank you Shushu, the `3` in the URL is a profile ID that I want to pass on to another URL. I have `node/1221/profile/chn/3` working because it has a panel that grabs the `%4` argument and passes it to a view inside the panel. Hope this gives more context.

Comment: ok, so what you have is a panel that shows the view. So, try to make a different panel that takes %1 and %2 to show the node, and %4 to show the profile. Even make it use a View and %1 and %2 as its arguments to get the wanted node. I think it will be much better solution then playing with the URL Alter hooks.

Comment: Thank you for helping, i don't understand though how using panels and arguments helps me make the URL nicer. It works as it is, but i want the url to look good. Actually I am half way there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://drupal.org/project/subpath_alias According to that module's description it does what you want it to do.

Comment: No this only deals with sub paths and I have tried it. I don't need to edit the sub paths, for instance node/1/edit to be alias/edit. What I need is to be able to create an alias that can take arguments. I am creating a module for it now.

Comment: With that module - if you give "node/1221" the alias "departments/pch" then requesting "departments/pch/profile/chn/3" will be result in same response as requesting "node/1221/profile/chn/3" - wasn't that what you wanted? The first part of the path will have an alias and the last part will be dynamic. You generate the aliases with http://drupal.org/project/pathauto

Comment: I didn't anticipate that usage of the module. Thank you for taking the time to explain it further to my hard head :) ...i will try it out right now.

Comment: @VoxPelli: I already had this installed but never realized that it had this functionality. The problem I have is that there are other paths that had everything but the last two parts of the element. Is there a hook api to use that I can leverage in my own module? Or do you have an example yourself.

Comment: I don't understand what hooks you would need? Pathauto would be enough for creating the basic aliases for the nodes and nothing else is needed - right?

Comment: Now I have some problems with access. It says that I am not allowed to create the aliases I want, i the admin/dev account though...getting more and more interesting.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If you want to use `hook_url_outbound_alter()` you need to upgrade to Drupal 7 since it doesn't exist on D6 and earlier.</strike>

If I were you, I would use aliases. Aliases work by rewriting the url to that `departments/pch/chn/profile/3` would be translated into `node/1221/profile/chn/3` which would be a valid Drupal path for your installation.

The thing is that what you got is a bit site specific, so you'll need to create your own system to create the aliases in your custom module instead of relying on path auto.

I don't know the semantics of your urls, so I can't help you how you should create the aliases. Most likely you can do it when a new node is created. Take a look at [`pathauto_create_alias`](http://api.lullabot.com/pathauto_create_alias) it should help you along most of the way.

Using aliases should be more maintainable and some modules hook into this allowing you to do other things. Using `custom_url_rewrite_xxx` can quickly become messy quick easily, especially if you need to add a lot of rules. It will probably be quicker to use now, but if you have to maintain the site, this is something that can lead some serious WTF 1 year from now.

#### hook_url_outbound_alter

If you do decide to take this route, you need to change the `$path` variable and not the `$result`. You can take a look at the url_alter.api.php for guidance, an example of usage is:

```
function hook_url_inbound_alter(&$result, $path, $path_language) {
  global $user;

  // Change all requests for 'article/x' to 'node/x'.
  if (preg_match('|^article(/.*)|', $path, $matches)) {
    $path = 'node'. $matches[1];
  }
  // Change all requests to 'e' to the user's profile edit page.
  if ($path == 'e') {
    $path = 'user/'. $user->uid .'/edit';
  }
}
```

Comment: It does exist in Drupal 6 as I stated in the title I am using a module called URL alter. Using my "own system"? As in a module that does all of it for me? Or mod_rewrite rules? I don't want to use mod_rewrite since I need to use this for possibly different path. The user should also be able to write the id 5 or 10 and get a new profile so I need that part to be dynamic . . . Taking a look at pathauto now.

Comment: Well I don't want to create an alias for each ID, that just to messy. I want to have it happen dynamically.

Comment: Not true that you need Drupal 7 - hook_url_outbound_alter() originates from the Drupal 6 module Url Alter: http://drupal.org/project/url_alter

Comment: @WmasterJ I missed you were using a contrib module, anyways I updated my answer to show you how to use the hook, though I warn against using this technique.

Comment: I have seen this documentation before but it didn't make sense to me at the time. I undestand your warning but i think that using a GUI for this instead should help. Currently I am looking at creating a test version that enables me to create aliases with paths. Then I want to see if I can translate that into a GUI where rules with simple CRUD enabled. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: I actually used the script in my example using the URL Alter modules GUI and it worked. But I am having problems with implementing it using the hook provided.

Comment: According to the documentation it's $path that needs to be rewritten, but according to Dave Reid (http://drupal.org/node/1015158#comment-3902878) the creator of the module it is $result (confusing no?)...so to all of you out there, it's $result. And also i realized I need to: **implement a hook_boot() with nothing in it + go to modules list and click submit** this way drupals bootstrap system knows that hook_boot has been implemented and the module will then load earlier. . . and still it isn't working, but now I atleast have done everything needed.