# Drupal arguments in a menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

By default on a page I have the following menu:

```
Profile /profile
Albums /album
Awards /awards
```

Going to any of those pages will load the page default.

If I go to a page on my site such as /mycontent/1 I wish to change a the menu to be the following.

```
Profile /profile/1
Albums /album/1
Awards /awards/1
```

I want to pass the argument (nid) to the menu. Is this possible?

**Update**
The selected answer does do what I asked. I however have changed how I am doing things to use Panels to display the content. I am then using some CSS and JavaScript to hide and show content. With views caching it seems to be working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,use arg(0),arg(1), or arg(2) depending on which variable you want to use. It will use the path like the indexes of an array (0/1/2/3/4/etc...). Drupal will send you these variables as they were before the path was aliased if that is something that has been applied to it. Why are you passing the variable? There is probably a better way to do it the "Drupal" way..

Comment: If i was viewing a node I may have several views where I wish to pass the nid to those pages. I want the links to be context aware. Part of me is thinking I should go the panels route.

Comment: Panels or the Views module are probably both good ways to go, I find Views more flexible but they both accomplish the same functionality much of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am working on this same problem currently where I need to translate an aliased path: `dept/profile/1` to load `node/1223/profile/1` where `1` is the ID of the profile to show.

What I am using now is the URL Alter module and implementing the hook it gives to enable this feature. If you are interested in this maybe we can see if it is possible to get module out with a GUI.

My thread on this that is active now: [Using module: url_alter and it's hook: hook_url_outbound_alter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587660/using-module-url-alter-and-its-hook-hook-url-outbound-alter)

I am using a node that houses a panel which has a view inside it, for reasons that are site specific.